# Change orientation of a grid view

Tags: html, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have the following orientation view

[image]

I wanted to know if is it possible to change the orientation only of the column "Tempo" to horizontal.

I am using HTML and VB.Net with WebForms and my database is MySQL, follow the code to fill the grid view:

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim modelo As String = txtModelo.Text
    Dim linha As String = txtLinha.Text
    Dim data As String = txtData.Text
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tempo where timermodelo = @timermodelo and timerlinha = @timerlinha and timerdata = @timerdata")
            Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timermodelo", modelo)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timerlinha", linha)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timerdata", data)
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt
                    GridView1.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

The Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  Style="text-align: center;" CssClass="gridview"
runat = "server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="OnDataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="timeroperador" HeaderText="Operador" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="timerposto" HeaderText="Posto" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="timertempo" HeaderText="Tempo" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="#ffffff"  HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"/>
```

I tried to put `HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"` but it did not do anything

The desired result would like this:

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| OPERADOR |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Nonato   | 92.0  |  94.0 |  92.0 |  95.0 |  94.0 |
| Adriano  | 122.0 | 120.0 | 121.0 | 119.0 | 117.0 |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Some help please?

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: Hi, It should look like this: https://imgur.com/YBTsZrL with the column "Tempo" in horizontal. I hope you can visualize the image let me know if you cant

Comment: The term you'll want to search for is "transposing columns". Although in this case, it appears to be a bit more than that. For instance, where do the numbers 1-5 come from? Where are Cesar and Paulo?

Comment: Thanks. I will check that! About the numbers, let me explain a little bit of background. I have a timer to time a process, it returns the values in seconds, so the number 1 is the first time registered, the number 2 is the second and so on... I would like to show them horizontally. Cezar and Paulo are still there, I just did not put on the image. what it matters is to show these times horizontally